# TextField in Material Design UI Android

Tags: android, material-design, textfield, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I want to do a editext like below. I dont want to use TableRow to do this. Is there any way to do in Material Design TextField?
I set background for TextInputEditText rounded shape.

There are some problem with my design.

- first line I want to have more space between text and image.
- second line picture and text not in the same line.
- background of TextInputLayout cannot change.

Please help me. Thank in advance!

[image: wantodo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:placeholderText="Name"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
            app:startIconTint="@color/...."
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.rounded"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

with:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve using material design TextFiled

- if you want more space between text and Image use

> `android:drawablePadding="16dp"`

- Set Text Gravity

> `android:gravity="center"`

- for round corner radius  without out line border set style

> `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"`
> Blockquote

if you want to achieve round coroner border set

```
 app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="32dp"
 app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="32dp"
 app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="32dp"
 app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="32dp"
```

Below are the code snippet

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout   
 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                 android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                 app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="32dp"
                 app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="32dp"
                 app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="32dp"
                 app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="32dp"
                 app:boxStrokeColor="@color/color_red"
                 app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_user">
 
                 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
 
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:drawablePadding="16dp"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:hint="hint"
                     android:inputType="text" />
             </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```